# Get current Spring transaction in JUnit and commit it

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit, transactions

is it possible to get current Spring transaction in JUnit?

I want to test JPA in DAO. And DAO do not have transactions. In tests spring create transaction for every method. I want transaction to be commited somewhere in the middle of test. Need it to test DB status. Only solution I found is to create @Rule for every method.

Comment: You don't need to commit only flush. Just inject the entity manager into your test... Do `em.flush()` and check what you want.

Comment: I tried, and database is not updated till transaction not commited. So I can not check what is in database with another connection.
Or maybe I can get current entityManager connection, and connect with it to check database?

Comment: Well of course you cannot with a different connection as it is only visible to the current connection. Use the same entity manager (or even better a plain sql call) to check the result. After the flush, do a `clear` and execute your query.

Comment: Not sure that I understood correctly. Transaction not commited, so no rows in database. If I will use same entity manager, I will get result from orm, even if there is no data in table. Is it right?

Comment: Please read the comment again (and how ORMs work). Hence the added `em.clear()` that clears your first level cache`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `TestTransaction` in order to manage spring test transactions:

```
TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
TestTransaction.end();
```

This will flag the current transaction for `commit` and end it. After that you can use `TestTransaction.start()` to start a new transaction.

Comment: added `TestTransaction.flagForCommit()` and `@TestExecutionListeners`.  Still entities were not commited to database

Comment: This worked well. flush() did not commit to database until the transaction has ended. In the Junit case, the current thread does receive the updated flushed object but other threads receive old object since the transaction is not committed. But using TestTransaction worked to test multi Threaded code from JUnit. Thanks.

Comment: If you are expecting an exception that will roll back your transaction do not use `flagForCommit();` or you get `UnexpectedRollbackException`

Answer (score 1):

You can :

- Inject the EntityMananger in your test
- Call flush() after the invocation of your DAO
- Use this EntityManager to test the db

It's always better to keep the default behavior of spring on transaction/rollback in order to minimize side-effects between tests

Comment: looks like flush() not commiting, because transaction managed by spring test context, and it waiting it to be commited?

If I keep default transaction behaviour, what is best way to test DAO methods?

Comment: flush() send the jpa cache to the db. the transaction is not commited, but the db is synchronized. you can then test the db with the same EntityManager (ie, same connection/same tx)

Comment: This worked for, although I used Spring-Data repositories and AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests methods for the checking.

Comment: flush() does not commit to database until the transaction has ended. In the Junit case, the current thread does receive the updated flushed object but other threads receive old object since the transaction is not committed. Still trying to solve the issue.